# Computing pushforward measures explicitly

Tags: measure-theory

> Between the usual measurable sets $\mathbb{R}$ and
>    $S^1\subset\mathbb{R}^2$, there is a measurable mapping $$f:
>  \mathbb{R}\to S^1$$ given by $f(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$. The Lebesgue
>    measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ can therefore be pushforwarded to a
>    mesure $\hat\mu$ on $S^1$, given by
>    $$\hat\mu(A)=\mu(f^{-1}(A))=\int_{f^{-1}(A)} 1\ dt$$ for all $A\subset
>  S^1$ measurable.

I was wondering if there was a possibility to express this measure as
$$\hat\mu(A)=\int_{A} ???\ d\underline x,$$
where this is the usual Lebesgue integral of $S^1\subset\mathbb{R}^2$.

If we were doing the pushforward between to measurable spaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$, this would be possible: the question marks would be a jacobian. But I don't recall that there is a change of variables formula between two different dimensions...

Comment: Does the reply below answers your question? If yes, would you accept it, if not - could you explain what is still unclear to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lebesgue measure of $S^1$ as a Borel subset of $\mathbb R^2$ is zero hence what you ask cannot be done: for every density $\varphi$, $\int\limits_{S^1}\varphi(x)\mathrm d\text{Leb}_2(x)=0$ because $\text{Leb}_2(S^1)=0$, hence one would get $\hat\mu(S^1)=0$ although you ask that $\hat\mu(S^1)=\mu(\mathbb R)=+\infty$.

Note that $\hat\mu$ as you define is such that $\hat\mu(A)$ is either $0$ or $+\infty$, for every measurable $A\subseteq S^1$:

- If $\text{Leb}_1(f^{-1}(A)\cap[0,2\pi))\ne0$, then $\text{Leb}_1(f^{-1}(A))=\hat\mu(A)=+\infty$.
- If $\text{Leb}_1(f^{-1}(A)\cap[0,2\pi))=0$, then $\text{Leb}_1(f^{-1}(A))=\hat\mu(A)=0$.

Comment: Oh, right... So there is no more explicit way to express this measure ?

Comment: The last sentence of my post characterizes (quite explicitly) the (not very interesting) measure $\hat\mu$.

Comment: Hm, I took this example from the first one of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure. Is this "arc-length" measure really trivial ?

Comment: It is trivial in your post because you forgot the sentence "Let λ also denote the restriction of Lebesgue measure to the interval [0, 2π)" from the WP page. Note that if you quote correctly the WP page, the first paragraph of my answer still holds, replacing the $+\infty$ which ends it by $2\pi$.

Comment: I have some trouble understanding your last paragraph (and why there is a difference with considering the measure on the whole thing or not). Why a nonempty intersection with $[0,2\pi]$ would imply an infinite Lebesgue measure ?

Comment: Did you try to compute $\hat\mu(S^1)$?